# Opposite of numpy.broadcast_to

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there an opposite of [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), e.g. `numpy.project_to(array, function, axis)`?

```
np.project_to(
  np.array([[1,1,1], [2,1,3], [2,2,2]], dtype=float),
  lambda x, y: x/y,
  axis=1)
```

which would return

`array([ 1., 0.66666667,  0.5])`

Comment: Show through a sample what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you're asking for is a reduction along a particular axis: this can be done using the `reduce` method of any binary [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html). For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,1,3], [2,2,2]], dtype=float)

>>> np.divide.reduce(x, axis=1)
array([ 1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.5       ])
```

Comment: Yes. The division was just a random problem. but I just realized that there is also the apply_along_axis: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Comment: @HallgeirWilhelmsen `apply_along_axis()` is actually usually not what you want to use; it uses Python loops in the backend and isn't fast or optimized like other numpy functions. Typically, you want to use the axis argument available in numpy functions, and if that's not available for your particular function, then `reduce` is your best bet.